# UIAlertController shows blank titles of UIAlertActions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

Recently, I've finally refactored one legacy project and have turned all `UIAlertViews` and `UIActionSheets` to `UIAlertControllers`. But I've started to receive issues from customers, they saying that sometimes `UIAlertController` actions titles are blank. Like that way:

[image: blank actions titles example]

I can't reproduce this bug on my devices, do you have any ideas about possible reason?

**UPDATE:**

I believe, that problem is covered in that code, maybe tintColor of main window is somehow not default, and `UIAlertController` inherits it?

```
@implementation UIAlertController (WMC)

   - (void)show:(BOOL)animated {
        self.alertWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen 
   mainScreen].bounds];
       self.alertWindow.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

       id<UIApplicationDelegate> delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
       // Applications that does not load with UIMainStoryboardFile might not have a window property:
       if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(window)]) {
           // we inherit the main window's tintColor
           self.alertWindow.tintColor = delegate.window.tintColor;
       }

       // window level is above the top window (this makes the alert, if it's a sheet, show over the keyboard)
       UIWindow *topWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.lastObject;
       self.alertWindow.windowLevel = topWindow.windowLevel + 1;

       [self.alertWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
       [self.alertWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:self animated:animated completion:nil];
   }

   @end
```

Comment: Can you show some code for example what you had try out!

Comment: example : http://hayageek.com/uialertcontroller-example-ios/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I've found the solution. After some experiments, I've realized, that setting `tintColor` property for `UIWindow` results in changing tintColor of all `UIAlertActions` that presented in that `UIWindow`. So, I have changed the code of `UIAlertController` extension (NOTE: original code wasn't mine, I've found it on SoF, thanks to its author), that I use for presenting my alerts in that way:

```
#import "UIAlertController+WMC.h"

@implementation UIAlertController (Private)

@dynamic alertWindow;

- (void)setAlertWindow:(UIWindow *)alertWindow {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(alertWindow), alertWindow, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (UIWindow *)alertWindow {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(alertWindow));
}

@end

@implementation UIAlertController (WMC)

- (void)show {
    [self show:YES];
}

- (void)show:(BOOL)animated {
    self.alertWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.alertWindow.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    // window level is above the top window (this makes the alert, if it's a sheet, show over the keyboard)
    UIWindow *topWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.lastObject;
    self.alertWindow.windowLevel = topWindow.windowLevel + 1;

    [self.alertWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.alertWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:self animated:animated completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    // precaution to insure window gets destroyed
    self.alertWindow.hidden = YES;
    self.alertWindow = nil;
}
```

What I've exactly did is removed the part of inheriting main's window `tintColor`. Such complicated way of presenting alerts is the result of badly architectured navigation in my project. Thanks to all commentators for interest to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Title Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel action") style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
        NSLog(@"Cancle Tapped");
        [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];

    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];

    UIAlertAction *yesAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Yes", @"Yes action") style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
        NSLog(@"Yes Tapped");
    }];
    [alertController addAction:yesAction];

    UIAlertAction *noAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"No", @"No action") style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
        NSLog(@"No Tapped");
    }];
    [alertController addAction:noAction];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: my code is written exactly the same way, i'm very familiar with UIAlertController, but this issue is strange, and i still can't figure it out

Comment: @AleksandrSmirnov, can you tell me, in which device your customers getting blank title?

Comment: practically at every model @kuldeep

Comment: it's not possible, did you face this type of issue? may be it's strange issue.

Comment: @AleksandrSmirnov, pls update your question with code. so we can look that.

Comment: I've update the question, can you please look through the code, and confirm, if i'm right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156974/discussion-between-aleksandr-smirnov-and-kuldeep).